# Django get_or_create causing database error

Tags: python, django

Using `get_or_create` in Django causes the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\sande\Documents\projects\sbbetting\football\management\commands\scrape.py", line 12, in handle
    sofa.get_matches()
  File "C:\Users\sande\Documents\projects\sbbetting\football\common\sofascore.py", line 21, in get_matches
    country = Country.objects.get_or_create(id=country_id, name=country_name, defaults={"id": country_id, "name": country_name})[0]
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 538, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 402, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 256, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1098, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection       
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.init_connection_state()
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 231, in init_connection_state  
    if self.features.is_sql_auto_is_null_enabled:
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\features.py", line 81, in is_sql_auto_is_null_enabled
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 225, in _prepare_cursor
    self.validate_thread_sharing()
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 547, in validate_thread_sharing
    % (self.alias, self._thread_ident, _thread.get_ident())
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: DatabaseWrapper objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object with alias 'default' was created in thread id 14100 and this is thread id 67761232.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 224, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 279, in close
    self.validate_thread_sharing()
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 547, in validate_thread_sharing 
    % (self.alias, self._thread_ident, _thread.get_ident())
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: DatabaseWrapper objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object with alias 'default' was created in thread id 14100 and this is thread id 67761232.
```

I wrote the following code:

```
def get_matches(self):
        tournaments = self.data["sportItem"]["tournaments"]
        for tournament in tournaments:
            country_name = tournament["category"]["name"]
            country_id = tournament["category"]["id"]
            country = Country.objects.get_or_create(id=country_id, name=country_name, defaults={"id": country_id, "name": country_name})[0]
```

The following model corresponds with the 'Country' object:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: I'm not sure about the cause of this issue, but your traceback has `sofascore_id` instead of `id` in the `defaults` arg for `get_or_create`.

Comment: @kaveh That is unfortunately not causing the error

Comment: How are you using / calling ```get_matches```? Is this part of a view or model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the error Django is spitting out doesn't explain it; It looks like you improperly assigned a value to the model *`id` field*. If you're assigning a value to the model `id`, it's field classifier, aka `models.IntegerField()`, needs to have `primary_key` set to `True`, otherwise the id field is automatically assigned a unique incremented integer value by Django's internals. Attempting to define the `id` field otherwise will override Django's internal value throwing multiple unrelated errors in the process. I used to get around this problem by treating the `id` field as a reserved value. But simply adding the `primary_key=True` should be sufficient because when it's set Django won't provide the `id` key automatically.

For simplicity's sake, here's what that Model should look like:

```py
class Country(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And one last thing; assigning the primary key of a different model type to the current model's primary key may also yield errors. This one I'm not sure about unfortunately and I'm too lazy to write up a test case to double check myself. So if the above solution fails try changing `id` to `category_id` within the `Country` model definition, which will leave the unique `Country.id` automatically generated by Django intact, and is much more reflective of the value's nature.

Here are the [Docs for Django Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/) that I used to double check myself; it's been a while since I've used Django and I'm a bit rusty.